# How to use x3dom.swf when i want to show 3d objects on IE?

Tags: x3d

I noticed that x3d can show 3d objects by using x3dom.swf file but i don't know how to do it?
Are there any example or document can teach me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean x3d or x3dom but you can get the x3dom swf file from here http://www.x3dom.org/?page_id=7

Then place it in your root folder and open your x3dom project It should work fine.